# Will a Lock-in amplifier induce a dc voltage when an ac modulation is applied to a junction?

Tags: signal

As it is well known, by applying the ac modulation, the current across can be expressed by a taylor expansion as:

[image]

assuming a nonlinearity in the derivative conductance. An additional dc current appears. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming pure-sin voltage drive, the current will have 2nd and 3rd and 4rth and 5th etc energies.

The 2nd harmonic, summed with fundamental, yields an imbalanced signal....DC offset.